# Shopping cart counter in AngularJS 2

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project where I need a shopping cart icon with counter. I'm using AngularJS 2, and got stuck somewhere. I need a icon of a shopping cart with a counter in the header. When someone removes an item from the shopping cart I would like the number in the header to decrease. Because the header and shopping cart are 2 different components and both have a different controller, I don't understand how I can notify the header that there has been an item removed from the shopping cart.

Kind regards

**Update:**
I found the solution myself, by using a shared service this can be realized.
You just need to declare a variable in the service called 'quantity', inject the service in the constructor of the header component and in the template of the header you use 'yourService.quantity'.

Comment: Angular2 is not angularjs. Fix your tags. Also, use services. Create a Subject (if typescript) and send a signal through it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `EventEmitter` API and `@Output` decorator.

Let's assume we have a parent `Component` and setup a function called myValueChange on the class that we want to invoke when we bind it to a component called `CounterComponent’s`:

```
// app.component.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CounterComponent} from './counter.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    .app {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px;
      background: #f5f5f5;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <counter [counterValue]="myValue"></counter>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [CounterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myValue:number = 2;
  myValueChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

On the class `AppComponent` we’ve declared `myValueChange` which accepts event as an argument. Next we need to create a custom attribute name on the `<counter>` Component to hook this function into, let’s call it `counterChange`:

```
// app.component.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CounterComponent} from './counter.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    .app {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px;
      background: #f5f5f5;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <counter [counterValue]="myValue" (counterChange)="myValueChange($event);"></counter>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [CounterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myValue:number = 2;
  myValueChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Note how we’ve used `(counterChange)` with parentheses around it, this tells Angular that this is an event binding, similar to `(click)`. Now we need to mirror this API inside the `CounterComponent`.

```
 // counter.component.ts
 import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'counter',
   styles: [`
     // omitted
   `],
   template: `
     // omitted
   `
 })
 export class CounterComponent {
   @Input() counterValue = 0;
   @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();
   increment() {
     this.counterValue++;
     this.counterChange.emit({
       value: this.counterValue
     })
   }
   decrement() {
     this.counterValue--;
     this.counterChange.emit({
       value: this.counterValue
     })
   }
 }
```

Note how `@Output` counterChange is set to a new instance of `EventEmitter`, this `@Output` decorator makes the `counterChange` property available as an event binding like we saw in the above template `(counterChange)`.

Nearly there, we would like to tell the parent Component that the `counterChange` event has happened when the child `Component` actually updates the value, which as we know happens on a click event. Let’s emit an event there, as it seems a logical place to do so:

```
// counter.component.ts
...
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input() counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();
  increment() {
    this.counterValue++;
    this.counterChange.emit({
      value: this.counterValue
    })
  }
  decrement() {
    this.counterValue--;
    this.counterChange.emit({
      value: this.counterValue
    })
  }
}
```

Note that we're emitting an `Object` with a property of value, you don’t have to do this however it looks nicer when using the event in a callback in the parent (event.value being more explicit).

Our parent Component can now fetch the `$event` Object, as we’ve passed it into the template using `(counterChange)="myValueChange($event);"`.

```
// app.component.ts
...
export class AppComponent {
  public myValue:number = 2;
  myValueChange(event) {
    // result: { value: <number> }
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

And that's it.